# How do i show data from multiple tables in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, join, datagridview

```
Curriculum table
===
CurriculumID (PK, auto-increment)
CurriculumName Varchar(255)

GradeLevel table
===
GradeLevelID (PK, auto-increment)
GradeLevel Varchar(255)
CurriculumID (foreign key to Curriculum)

SubjectCreator table
===
SubjectID(PK, auto-increment)
SubjectName Varchar(255)
SubjectDescription Varchar(255)
GradeLevelID (foreign key to GradeLevel)
```

So Far these are my codes
i don't know the Query to show 3 tables. only tried 2 Tables.
these are the codes for 2 tables.
    string sql = "select GradeLevelID, GradeLevelName, CurriculumName from GradeLevelCreator
                  inner join CurriculumCreator on GradeLevelCreator.CurriculumID = CurriculumCreator.CurriculumID";

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=TOSHIBA-PC\\KENNETH;Initial Catalog=HSPAEnrollmentSystem;Integrated Security=True";
string sql = "";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "GradeLevelCreator");
connection.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "GradeLevelCreator";
```

i think i just need the query to Show multiple or 3 tables. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can join more than 2 tables when querying.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191430%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement:

```
SELECT s.SubjectID, s.SubjectName, s.SubjectDescription,
g.GradeLevel, c.CurriculumName FROM SubjectCreator s
INNER JOIN GradeLevel g ON s.GradeLevelID = g.GradeLevelID
INNER JOIN Curriculum c ON g.CurriculumID = c.CurriculumID
```